# Classical mechanics centripetal acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

[image]

How can centripetal acceleration provide normal contact force when it's not in the same direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey its just that the problem here is confusing you with its language .

yes normal is absolutely nullifying the weight pull on the ball thats why the ball rolls or moves while still staying in contact with the tube or groove's surface.

the question meant what was the force that is acting on the ball while its moving in the circular path inside the groove. thats it its just the language confusing us buddy have a good day

keep learning

and yeah the answer is centripetal force thats making the ball move in circular path

its the product of mass of ball and centripetal acceleration the ball is subjected to. thats the answer and its perfectly right.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Centripetal means "center pointing," and points to the center of the circle. So the centripetal acceleration and the normal force are indeed in the same direction.

FYI, it's much preferred to type out the excerpt from the text in question rather than provide a picture.

Comment: isn't normal force perpendicular to the surface so they both make a 90 degree angle?

Comment: Drawing a picture will help.  Yes, normal force is perpendicular to the surface, so it points radially inward towards the center of the circle. That is also the direction the acceleration points. They are related via $F=ma$

Comment: normal force is acting out of the plane and centripetal acceleration is acting on the plane towards the centre so how??

Comment: @Rampal *It's much preferred to type out the excerpt from the text in question rather than provide a picture.* A picture rotated 90 degrees is even worse than a proper picture.

Comment: Read the question carefully. "find the normal contact force by the side wall of the groove" – the wall is pushing the block towards the center of the circle,  in the plane , and the block is therefore accelerating towards the center, in the plane.

Comment: still dont understand thanks for responding

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a table, and on the table there is a circular vertical (upright) wall. Now there is another upright wall of a slightly larger radius with the same center as the previous one. So now there is a sort of passage of some width (difference of radii of the two circles). The question says that a ball is moving **in this passage**. Since the passage is a circle, the ball is in circular motion. The normal they talk about is not the normal between the table (horizontal surface) and the ball- that is absolutely upwards (out of the plane) and as you said that could not provide centripetal force/acceleration. The picture of the green and blue pen you uploaded describes that case. What the question means by normal is the normal with the (outer) vertical wall that the ball is in contact with while it moves through that "passage".

Now for your other question about the car: when the car tires turn, the direction of friction between the tires and the road changes so that it points inward and this provides the required centripetal force now.

**Note:** It would make more sense to say "normal force providing centripetal acceleration" instead of the other way around- centripetal acceleration isn't a special kind of acceleration, it is just the acceleration that is a necessary condition for circular motion- some force must *act as the centripetal force* (such as tension, friction, normal etc.) and *provide* the required centripetal acceleration (in this case it's the normal).